# Install google client library with conda

Tags: python, google-api, pip, google-cloud-platform, conda

No tengo mucha experiencia programando y quiero activar la API de google drive, mi distribución de python es spyder y mi pregunta es si hay algun problema en instalar la libereria de google client con PIP en lugar de usar conda, ya que en la pagina solo se muestra la instalacion con PIP (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que lei de tu problema con el `pip` lo más seguro es que lo estés corriendo desde tu terminal y no desde la terminal que tiene `Anaconda` incorporada, verifica si puede ser eso.

En caso que no, te recomendaría desinstalaras anaconda y lo volvieras a instalar, asegurándote que se instale dentro del `path` (para hacer esto solo es marcar una casilla de verificación en el proceso de instalación).

Comment: Por favor evita responder a preguntas escritas en un idioma distinto al usado en la plataforma, pues eso es motivo de cierre

Comment: muchas gracias, lo que suecede es que anteriormente tenia anaconda y python 3.8 en mi pc, anaconda no estaba en el path pero python si y al usar pip para instalar una libreria luego me salio un aviso diciendo que spyder tenia un error de registro y ya no podia iniciarse, pero según lo que me dices si ahora anaconda esta en el path puedo usar pip sin ningun problema?
Te agradezco mucho por tus aclaraciones